# How to fix OpenGL artefacts (small lines over the each rendering texture)?

Tags: opengl

I use OpenGL in my project that is basically clone of Mario game. There are how artefacts looks like: small lines over the each rendering texture.

[image: Artefacts]

```
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glPushMatrix();
glVertexPointer(VERTEX_POINTER_COUNT, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexPointer);
glColorPointer(COLOR_POINTER_COUNT, GL_FLOAT, 0, colorPointer);
glTexCoordPointer(TEXTURE_COORD_POINTER_COUNT, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoordPointer);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
glPopMatrix();

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL_ID);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try put more effort in the title of you question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

These two lines tell OpenGL that those textures should wrap around when accessing values outside of the texture bounds, which the linear filtering does.

Change it to clamp instead.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```